# Convert mbox to eml, or similar deduplicate internal duplicate email messages

Tags: linux, email, macos, file-converter, duplicate-files

I have many mbox files with internally overlapping content so there are duplicates that cannot be found directly. I'd like to extract EML files for each message and then have them as loose files for interoperability between different systems. Can I import all the mbox files into Apple macOS built-in email client and then merge everything and duplicate, or should I buy or get some other software for my aim? I looked at [MacUncle](https://www.macuncle.com/mbox/eml/) and [MacMister](https://www.macmister.com/mbox/) email converters which can convert from MBOX to EML files, but what I'm aiming to do is organize many different MBOX files into something that is structured.

I found a [public open-source C++ program on GitHub](https://github.com/giomba/mbox2eml) that could do it, but I'd prefer something more tested and verified.